# Change registry key value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, tcp, registry

I'm trying to change TCP Enabled value of SQL Server 2008 R2, here the code :

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP", true);               
key.SetValue("Enabled", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

An error says :

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: From the docs: "If the specified subkey cannot be found, then null is returned."  You should check if `key` is null.

Comment: In what context are you doing this? There are security and admin implications.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Which implications do you mean? could you explain please

Comment: You need admin access to enable tcp/ip, any admin can disable it, enabling it vastly expands the attack surface of your sql server and even enabled you still have to deal with firewalls and such.

Comment: @Joe yes it returns null, what's the problem then ?